# knex / postgresql updating a foreign key to null

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am using knex.js with postgresql
So I have a table with a nullable foreign key.

shortened version:

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('Note', function (table) {
    table.string('id').primary()
    table
      .string('sourceId')
      .references('id')
      .inTable('Source')
      .onDelete('SET NULL')
      .index()
  })
}

exports.down = function (knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('Note')
}
```

I am able to create a Note with or without a sourceId. However, if I create a Note with a sourceId and then update it to set the sourceId to NULL, the update does not work. I do not get an error message, but the foreign key is not removed.

For example if I create a Note with:

```
{
  id: '123',
  sourceId: '456'
}
```

and then try to update it:

```
const result = await Note.query().updateAndFetchById(id, {
  id: '123',
  sourceId: null
})
```

The result I get is :

```
Note {
id: '123',
sourceId: '456'
}
```

I have no problem if I try to update other nullable values to null (as long as they are not foreign keys) and  I can update the sourceId to a different source's id.
If I try to update a not nullable foreign key to null, I get an error. But in the above case, I get no error. It just doesn't update.

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: You are thinking about this in the wrong direction. The `Note` table is the referencing table, so `onDelete` and `onUpdate` are the actions taken when the referenced table, `Source` has its `id` value either deleted or updated. The `SET NULL` would happen when `Source.id` is deleted/updated and is propagated to all rows in `Note` that have that `id` as their FK value. You can't push that uphill from `Note`.

Comment: I wasn't trying to change the Source.id or anything in the Source table. I just want to take a Note that points to a Source, and make it point to nothing instead. The Source would still exist. I guess I didn't need to include the .onDelete line in my example.

Comment: Any solution for this? Stuck today with the same problem :(